# rdlc in MVC shows single record when convert to PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, rdlc

I have a list of customerprofile in view and want to convert to PDF using rdlc control. Now it shows only one record, when convert to PDF. My controller action is follwoing :

```
 public ActionResult CompetitorProfileListFormat(string id)
        {
            LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Report"), "CompetitorProfileReport.rdlc");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                lr.ReportPath = path;
            }
            else
            {
                return View(_customerProfileViewModel.CompetitorProfile());
            }

            ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("DsCompetitorReport", _customerProfileViewModel.CompetitorProfile());
            lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
            lr.Refresh(); 

            string reportType = id;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension;

            string deviceInfo =

            "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "  <OutputFormat>" + id + "</OutputFormat>" +
            "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
            "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
            "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
            "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
            "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
            "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>";

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;

            renderedBytes = lr.Render(
                reportType,
                deviceInfo,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtension,
                out streams,
                out warnings);


            return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
        }
```

I list all record in view and convert to pdf link is like following :

```
<div style="padding:10px; border:1px solid black">
    <div><a href="@Url.Action("CompetitorProfileListFormat", new { id = "PDF" })"> Get Report PDF</a></div>
    <div><a href="@Url.Action("CompetitorProfileListFormat", new { id = "Excel" })"> Get Report Excel</a></div>
    <div><a href="@Url.Action("CompetitorProfileListFormat", new { id = "Word" })"> Get Report Word</a></div>
    <div><a href="@Url.Action("CompetitorProfileListFormat", new { id = "Image" })"> Get Report Image</a></div>
</div>
```

Now when i debuggin i got 5 records in dataset and report. But when i click convert to pdf it shows only one record as shown in image[image]

[image: view contains list of competitor]

My rdlc file is look like follwing :[image: rdlc file format]

my actionmethod for view display is following:

```
 public ActionResult CompetitorProfileListRpt()
        {
            return View(_customerProfileViewModel.CompetitorProfile());
        }
```

Is there any adjustments i do with my rdlc file or some other ?
Can anyone help me to do this....
Thanks in advance .....

Comment: Are you sure your RDLC Report is filled correctly (without exporting to PDF)? How is your report build? From your screenshot it looks like you're not using an actual table but some custom layout. If you're using textboxes make sure that the fields aren't getting only the first values of your datasource (`=First(Fields!MyColumn.Value)`)

Comment: i am sure I am using Fields!MyColumn.Value for all textboxes here..

Comment: And you only get this problem when exporting to PDF? Word, Image etc works fine?

Comment: no i am getting the same problem in other methods also..

Comment: I'm unable to help you with the information you've posted so far. Could you show me how your RDLC Report looks like?

Comment: i updated my question please check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshot of the RDLC Report you posted, it seems like you placed TextBoxes outside of a repeatable report item.

You'll have to use the `List` item and place the data you wish to display for each record inside of it. So move the TextBoxes inside of the lists's `Rectangle`. This will then grow/repeat depending on the number of rows inside of your datasource.

A great tutorial can be found [here](http://gotreportviewer.com/masterdetail/index.html), I believe option #2 is exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried by using list.. I t shows 5 records one by one in same row i.e under competior number it list all 5 numbers in dataset and for company name it lists 5 company names in single page one by one

Comment: I believe you're using the wrong expressions inside the textboxes. Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.mstecharticles.com/2013/04/c-building-rdlc-report-template-and.html) will help you more, it's a complete guide with videos.

Comment: i used table controls in rdlc files for list the values from dataset.. but for now the customized format could not use this table as it lists all values not one record per page..

Comment: Did you actually follow the tutorial I linked in my answer? It explains how to use lists to group as much data you want and repeat it for each record.